# Is is possible to delete a table in a worksheet with epplus?

Tags: epplus

In Epplus Worksheets have the member `ExcelTableCollection Tables` for adding and editing tables. However, you cannot delete a table. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WorkSheet.Tables.Delete() is now implemented.